# Maven publisher plugin with griffon

Tags: maven, griffon

Using griffon 0.9.4, I installed maven-publisher plugin but I see no pom.xml generated.
Furthermore, when launching `griffon maven-install`, I get the following error:

```
No such property: config for class: MavenInstall
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.GriffonScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GriffonScriptRunner.java:659)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.GriffonScriptRunner.callPluginOrGriffonScript(GriffonScriptRunner.java:518)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.GriffonScriptRunner.executeCommand(GriffonScriptRunner.java:300)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.GriffonScriptRunner.main(GriffonScriptRunner.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.support.GriffonStarter.rootLoader(GriffonStarter.java:198)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.cli.support.GriffonStarter.main(GriffonStarter.java:223)
```

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, apparently this plugin also requires an upgrade to properly work with 0.9.4. I cannot promise it will be as fast as with wsclient but we'll try to get it fixed soon.

Cheers,
Andres